Let $\mathcal A$ be the set of all principal ideals of $R$ then $\mathcal A$ has at least one maximal element.
Let $\mathcal A$ be the set of all principal ideals of $R$ then $\mathcal A$ has at least one maximal element. Moreover, these maximal elements are prime.
My attempt: Let $\Delta$ to be set of all principle ideals of $R$. Clearly, $\Delta$ is not empty because $(0)$ ideal in $\Delta$. Now, consider a chain of ideals $\mathcal C=\{I_i \}_i$ which is ordered by inclusion. Then $J=\bigcup I_i$ is an ideal of $R$ because ideals are ordered by inclusion. To have upper bound for the chain $\mathcal C$, my claim is that $J$ is also principal.
Actually if $R$ is PID then rest is clear however I couldn't show $J$ is principal and the maximal element should be a prime.

Take $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ which is not a PID (for example the ideal $(2, x)$ is not principal). Principal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are generated by single polynomials so if we construct a chain of principal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such as $(0) \subset (x) \subset (x^2) \subset (x^3) \subset \dots$ the union $J$ of these ideals is not principal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ because there is no single polynomial that can generate all the powers of $x$ simultaneously.

@Mechap The inclusions you wrote are false. $(x^2)$ is contained in $(x)$, not the other way around. The union of these ideals is just $(x)$.

@Mark You are absolutely right. Actually when I saw this comment, I wondered should I look for a counter example.

For those intrigued by why certain families' maximal elements are prime, an obligatory plug for Lam, Tsit Yuen, and Manuel L. Reyes. "A prime ideal principle in commutative algebra." Journal of Algebra 319.7 (2008): 3006-3027. is in order.

None of the statements are true in general. 
A maximal element of the set $\mathcal{A}$ might not be a prime ideal. Indeed, let $k$ be a field, and let $R=k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$. Then the ideal $(z)$ is maximal in $\mathcal{A}$ ; if you try to write $z=ab$ with $a,b\in R$, then writing $a,b$ as polynomial in $x,y,z$, you will see that it is necessary for one of $a$ or $b$ to be a non zero constant, thus a unit.
But $(z)$ is not prime, indeed, $xy\in (z)$, but none of $x$ nor $y$ is in $(z)$.
Moreover, $\mathcal{A}$ might not have maximal element. Indeed, if $\mathcal{A}$ has a maximal element, then $R$ would have a prime principal ideal. There are plenty of counter-examples ;
Let $A$ be a ring where every non unit element is nilpotent. Then $A\backslash A^{\times}$ is an ideal, consisting of every nilpotent element. As it is an ideal, $A$ is local, and as it consists of every nilpotent element, it consists of the intersection of all primes. Thus, in such a ring, $A$ has only one prime ideal. (In fact, it is an equivalence, a ring with only one prime is such that every element of $A\backslash A^{\times}$ is nilpotent). If the only prime of $A$ is principal, say it is $(a)$, say that $a^n=0$, then every non unit element $b$ of $A$ satisfy $b^n=0$. 
Thus, if we are able to find such a ring $A$, where there are nilpotent of index $n$ for every $n$, then such a ring would have no principal prime ideal.
Let $k$ be a field, and let $A=k[(t_n)_{n\geq 2}]/(t_n^n = 0)$. The set of units is the set of polynomial with non zero constant (indeed, units are clearly of this form, and reciprocally, such an element is a unit + a nilpotent, thus a unit). Thus ever non unit element is nilpotent. Moreover, there are no integer $n$ such that $a^n=0$ for every non unit $a$, as $t_{n+1}^n \neq 0$ for $n\geq 2$. Hence our ring is a counter example.
There is a whole family of rings that satisfy those properties. For example, artinian local rings with a non prinipal maximal ideal. Those are exactly the non principal artinian local rings (a theorem of Cohen-Kaplansky shows that a ring where every primes are principal is a PID).

Maybe, I don't know, I will check wether or not it is true that a maximal element of $\mathcal{A}$ is prime. Whatever, it doesn't change the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ doesn't have maximal element in general -- see my answer

Of course, I just meant to draw your attention to the one thing, not dispute the whole answer :)

No problem ! I am thinking if the maximality implies primality, then I will edit my post

@rschwieb I proved that a maximal element of $\mathcal{A}$ might not be prime. I also simplified my couter example for the non existence of maximal element of $\mathcal{A}$. Maybe the author of the question made the same reading error as I did

Thanks for taking the time for improvements!

I suppose that you mean that $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of principal idelas of $R$ different from $\mathcal{A}$. I also assume that $R$ is nontrivial. If so, it is then easy to show that if $R$ is a domain, then  $(\pi)\in\mathcal{A}$ is a maximal element (for the inclusion) if and only if $\pi$ is an irreducible element of $A$.
Hence, counterexamples may arise into ways:

if $R$ has no irreducible element, such that the ring of algebraic integers( or simpler: a field)

if $R$ has an irreducible element which is not prime, such has any noetherian domain which is not a UFD


